# SettingWithCopyWarning when trying to add new columns

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I get a SettingWithCopyWarning  @:

```
pred_data[pred_col_name] = model_rf.predict(pred_data[features])
```

whenever I try to add a column in the following function. I've tried using loc[:, "TEXT] to assign the column, but with no luck. I'm assuming there is some way to automate the column name creation and assignment. What am I missing?

```
def create_train_predict(train_data, pred_data, target, features, model_type):
    y = train_data[target]
    X = train_data[features]
    train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y)

    if model_type == "dt":
        model_dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
        model_dt.fit(train_X, train_y)
        pred_col_name = "dt_" + str(pred_data) + "_preds"
        pred_data[pred_col_name] = model_dt.predict(pred_data[features])
        print(mean_absolute_error(val_y, model_dt.predict(val_X)))
        return pred_data

    elif model_type == "rf":
        model_rf = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
        model_rf.fit(X, y)
        pred_col_name = "rf_" + str(pred_data) + "_preds"
        pred_data[pred_col_name] = model_rf.predict(pred_data[features])
        print(mean_absolute_error(val_y, model_rf.predict(val_X)))
        return pred_data
```

The full error:

```
/Users/jackmaling/PycharmProjects/AlphaDNA/digital_financial_tree_model/dt_and_rf_mod.py:47: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  pred_data[str(pred_col_name)] = model_rf.predict(pred_data[features])
```

The full code:

```
# Data Import
Fin_Actual_URLs_to2018 = pd.read_csv("/Users/.../Fin.Actual.URLs.to2018.csv")
URL_2019_Test_Data = pd.read_csv("/Users/.../URL.2019.Test.Data.csv")


# Cleaning Data
def drop_clean(df):
    df.dropna(axis=0)
    df = df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]
    return df

# Predicrtion-Generating Function
def create_train_predict(train_data, pred_data, target, features, model_type):
    y = train_data[target]
    X = train_data[features]
    train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y)

    if model_type == "dt":
        model_dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
        model_dt.fit(train_X, train_y)
        pred_col_name = "dt_" + str(pred_data) + "_preds"
        pred_data[pred_col_name] = model_dt.predict(pred_data[features])
        print(mean_absolute_error(val_y, model_dt.predict(val_X)))
        return pred_data

    elif model_type == "rf":
        model_rf = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
        model_rf.fit(X, y)
        pred_col_name = "rf_" + str(pred_data) + "_preds"
        pred_data[pred_col_name] = model_rf.predict(pred_data[features])
        print(mean_absolute_error(val_y, model_rf.predict(val_X)))
        return pred_data


Fin_Actual_URLs_to2018 = drop_clean(Fin_Actual_URLs_to2018)
URL_2019_Pred_Data = drop_clean(URL_2019_Test_Data)

features = ["QoQ.Sum.Total.Page.Visit.Delta.Prop", "QoQ.Mean.Weighted.Pageviews.Delta.Prop", "QoQ.Mean.Weighted.Time.on.Site.Delta.Prop", "QoQ.Weighted.Bounce.Rate.Delta.Prop", "QoQ.Sum.Unique.Visitors.Delta.Prop"]

Fin_Actual_URL_Preds = create_train_predict(Fin_Actual_URLs_to2018, URL_2019_Pred_Data, "rev_beat_miss", features, "rf")
pd.DataFrame.to_csv(Fin_Actual_URL_Preds, "/Users/.../Fin_Actual_URL_Preds.csv")
```

Comment: Can we see the full trace back and code? I am guessing this does not have to do with your function but rather you making a slice of a frame that is used in the function: `pred_data` is probably a slice of a larger frame

Comment: @It_is_Chris I've added the complete code to the original question

Comment: It looks like the problem is with your `drop_clean` function. Boolean indexing is creating a slice of a frame and not a copy. try changing `df = df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]` to `df = df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)].copy()`